# Use cv2.videocapture without it opening a window

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to use face detection but I do not want the video feed window to open up when I use videocapture, this is the code I'm working on:

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    
    _, img = cap.read()
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
cap.release()
```

I just want to somehow disable the video feed window that opens up automatically and instead get an output on the command line every time it detects a face.
I am using the code from here: https://github.com/adarsh1021/facedetection.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reomve `cv2.imshow('img', img)` and replace it with `print(faces)`

cv2.imshow() is responsible for opening of image window.